# Ruby DateTime range only has granularity of 1 day

Tags: ruby

It seems that in ruby DateTime ranges only have a granularity of exactly 1 day.

```
now = DateTime.new(2013,1,1)
#=> #<DateTime: 2013-01-01T00:00:00+00:00 ((2456294j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>

two_days_later = DateTime.new(2013,1,3)
#=> #<DateTime: 2013-01-03T00:00:00+00:00 ((2456296j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>

range = (now..two_days_later)
#=> #<DateTime: 2013-01-01T00:00:00+00:00 ((2456294j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>..#<DateTime: 2013-01-03T00:00:00+00:00 ((2456296j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>

tomorrow = DateTime.new(2013,1,2)
#=> #<DateTime: 2013-01-02T00:00:00+00:00 ((2456295j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>

range.include?(tomorrow)
#=> true

later_this_morning = now + 0.1
#=> #<DateTime: 2013-01-01T02:24:00+00:00 ((2456294j,8640s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>

range.include? later_this_morning
#=> false

# but .....

range.max
#<DateTime: 2013-01-03T00:00:00+00:00 ((2456296j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

The desired behavior is that it would only exclude the last second of the date range so that the max value would be `2013-01-02T23:59:59` and that any DateTime on today or tomorrow would be included in that range.

Is there a way to change the granularity of DateTime ranges?

Comment: No, Dates have a granularity of one day, DateTimes have a granularity under a second.

Answer (score 8):

It turns out I just needed to use `Range#cover?` rather than `Range#include?`

#### Further explanation

I believe that `Range#include?` will first convert the range to an array and then use `Array#include?` to see if the value is a member.

When you convert the range `(now...two_days_later)` to an Array it is the equivalent of an array containing **now** and **1 day from now**

```
[2013-01-01T00:00, 2013-01-02T00:00:00]
```

A comparable example is with a range of integers. `(1...5)`

By default integer ranges have a `step` of **1 integer**.

So `(1...5).to_a` would produce `[1,2,3,4]`

Therefore `(1...5).include?(3.14)` would also be false.

Comment: It’s worth noting that `Range#cover?` is also significantly faster than `Range#include?` for everything but Numerics & Strings.